# Ruby Curses - cannot load such file -- curses.so (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, curses

I have the following error:

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- curses.so (LoadError)
```

Here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.2.4'

# console
gem 'curses'
gem 'dispel'

# testing
gem 'rspec'
```

And the main file:

```
require 'dispel'

require_relative 'game'

module TheQuietWhite
  Dispel::Screen.open(colors:true) do |screen|
    game = Game.new
  end
end
```

I have the actual file, and I can't seem to be able to make Ruby load curses.so, despite it being there. I've tried installing and uninstalling Ruby curses several times, along with Ruby dispel.

I'm wondering if there's a bug in the code somewhere, but I haven't been able to find it at all.

Comment: It looks like your gems are installed for ruby `2.2.4` while you are using ruby `2.2.0` locally. If you're using `rbenv` do `rbenv local 2.2.4` in your project folder.

Comment: Doing `ruby -v` on the command line gives me 2.2.4, so that's strange. Put that seems to probably be the problem.